# Evaluation of $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{r=0}^{2015}\cos (rx)\cdot \sum_{r=0}^{2015}\sin (rx)dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluation of

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(1+\cos x+\cos 2x+.......+\cos2015 x\right)\cdot \left(1+\sin x+\sin 2x+.......+\sin 2015 x\right)dx$

$\bf{My\;  Trial \; Solution::}$ Using the formula :: $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{(n-1)}\cos \left\{a+r\cdot d\right\}=\frac{\sin \frac{n\cdot d}{2}}{\sin \frac{d}{2}}\cos x \left[\frac{2a+(n-1)d}{2}\right]$

and the formula :: $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{(n-1)}\sin \left\{a+r\cdot d\right\}=\frac{\sin \frac{n\cdot d}{2}}{\sin \frac{d}{2}}\sin x \left[\frac{2a+(n-1)d}{2}\right]$

So $\displaystyle 1+\cos x+\cos 2x+.......+\cos2015 x = 1+\frac{\sin (2008x)}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}\cos \left(\frac{2017 x}{2}\right)$

and $\displaystyle 1+\sin x+\sin 2x+.......+\sin 2015 x = 1+\frac{\sin (2008x)}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}\sin \left(\frac{2017 x}{2}\right)$

Now How can I solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: You do realize that the sine term with $r=0$ equals zero, not one. So the question in the title is different from the one in the body. This has caused difficulties for the answerers. The accepted answer is to the question in the title, but some others looked at the body. Please clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{2015}\cos (rx)$ is an even function and $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^{2015}\sin (rx)$ is an odd function, their product is an odd function. What is the integral on $[-\pi,\pi]$ of an odd function?

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ we have:
$$2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin(ax)\cos(bx)\,dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((a-b)x)\,dx + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin((a+b)x)\,dx = 0, $$
hence the integral equals:
$$ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} 1\cdot 1\,dx = \color{red}{2\pi}.$$